# Access violation reading location in dimensional matrix

Tags: c

I would like to get your help to understand and finish my program.

This is what I have to do:

> "You must exercise program that:
>   First. An absorbing two - dimensional integer arr [M] [N]. M - number of rows N - number of columns. (Matrix size was received from
>   the user)
>   Two. The program uses auxiliary functions "shift" moves the values ​​of the matrix to the right one place, as shown in the picture (2
>   entered instead of 1, 3 instead of 2, 4 instead of 3, ... 20 instead
>   of 19, first place 20).
>   Shift have to write a function and call her three times in the sample matrix loop .."

Example picture:
[image]

error msg:
[image]

After trying to solve the problem i gave up, i would like to get your help to understand what is wrong in my code.
Is it about the memory?
This is my code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "malloc.h"

void shift (int **arr,int rows,int cols);
void freemalloc ( int **arr,int rows);

void main()
{
    int **arr,cols,rows;
    int i,j;
    printf("please insert rows and columns of the matrix: ");
    scanf_s("%d%d",&rows,&cols);
    arr=(int **)malloc(rows*sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
        arr[i]=(int *)malloc(cols*sizeof(int));
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
        for (j=0; j<cols; j++)
        {
            printf("rows %d , cols %d :\n", i, j);
            scanf_s("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    shift (arr,rows,cols);
    freemalloc (arr,rows);
    system("pause");
    return ;
}

void shift (int **arr,int rows,int cols)
{
    int i,j,temp=0;
    for(i=0; i<rows ; i++ )
        for( j=0 ; j<cols ; j++);
    {
        temp=arr[i][j];
        arr[i][j]=arr[i][cols-1];
        arr[i][cols-1]=temp;
    }
    for(i=0; i<rows ; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<cols ; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void freemalloc ( int **arr,int rows)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0 ; i<rows ; i++)
    {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
}
```

Comment: If you include standard header files, like `stdio.h` use `<stdio.h>` instead. Also, you should not cast the return value of functions returning `void *`, like `malloc`.

Comment: As for your problem, run the program in a debugger, it will stop at the location of the crash, and you can then examine the function call stack and local variables and arguments.

Comment: You will want some type of delimiter when reading the values, otherwise scanf won't be able to tell them apart and you will likely end up using an uninitialized `cols` value: `scanf_s("%d %d",&rows,&cols);`

Comment: You seem to be writing in C. Your tag says "c++".  C and C++ are very different languages.

Comment: Mark,I have to post the whole code to get help. How i should do it?

Comment: I ran the debugger and i don't have the knowledge of finding what's wrong. i am newbie in this business.please point me what is wrong

Comment: I highly suspect this: `for( j=0 ; j<cols ; j++);` (note the semi-colon trailing) is *not* what you wanted.
`

Comment: Does the debugger catch the access violation? Does it give you a call stack? Which line of your code causes this?

Comment: Doctor love, it's send me to this line. in the fucntion temp=arr[i][j];

Comment: line 37 and it's catch the access violation

Comment: @n.m.: I've edited the tags, if you have enough reputation you can do so as well.

Answer (score 4):

I noted this in general-comment, and I'll amplify it here. This is wrong, and wiil result in **undefined behavior**:

```
for(i=0; i<rows ; i++ )
    for( j=0 ; j<cols ; j++); // <<== this is wrong.
{
    temp=arr[i][j];
    arr[i][j]=arr[i][cols-1];
    arr[i][cols-1]=temp;
}
```

That trailing semi-colon is outright wrong. With it, the code literally becomes this:

```
// A useless nested for loop that runs `i` to `rows` and `j to `cols`
for(i=0; i<rows ; i++ )
    for( j=0 ; j<cols ; j++);

// Now `i=rows` and `j=cols`. then you do this
temp=arr[i][j];
arr[i][j]=arr[i][cols-1];
arr[i][cols-1]=temp;
```

You're accessing memory you don't own, as `arr` is only indexible to `[rows-1][cols-1]` Anything outside that is undefined behavior.

**Correction**

```
for(i=0; i<rows ; i++ )
    for( j=0 ; j<cols ; j++) // note: no semi-colon.
    {
        temp=arr[i][j];
        arr[i][j]=arr[i][cols-1];
        arr[i][cols-1]=temp;
    }
```

Fix your code by removing that semi-colon, and at least that part of your problem is addressed. I cannot speak for other issues.

Finally, **enable your compiler warnings to pedantic levels.** Any reasonable compiler configured with properly heightened warnings would catch this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The error has been already pointed out in another answer, but let me give you another piece of good advice: **do not use pointers-to-pointers to represent multidimensional arrays.**

Also, **[do NOT cast the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).**

This is what you should do (should have done):

```
int (*mat)[width] = malloc(height * sizeof(*mat));
```